# how to edit modelform in django

Tags: django, django-forms

'Contact' is model,and 'ContactForm' is model form

urls.py

```
(r'^contact/edit/(?P<p_id>\d+)$',edit_contact_page),
```

views.py

```
def edit_contact_page(request,p_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST,instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/success')
    else:  
        obj=Contact.objects.get(pk=p_id)
        form=ContactForm(instance=obj)
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
        return render_to_response('registration/edit_contact.html',variables)


#edit_contact.html
<form method="post" action="/contact/success/"  class="form-signin">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.name.errors }}
    <label>Name</label>
    {{ form.name }}
    <br>
     {{ form.email.errors }}
    <label>Email</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <br>
     {{ form.msg.errors }}
    <label>Message</label>
    {{ form.msg }}
    <br>
    {{ form.phone.errors }}
    <label>Phone</label>
    {{ form.phone }}
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

## else part get instance well(bounded form), but post method neither save form in model nor gives validation error.

## request redirects to sucess.html template.

Comment: What is `obj` in `form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=obj)`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it is bounded form object....
form contain updated values..
any another way to do that?

Comment: Its actually nothing, its not declared anywhere in the block. I am talking about `obj` not `form`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid obj is model instance at given id..(Contact is model)

Comment: This line `obj=Contact.objects.get(pk=p_id)` needs to be the absolute first line of the method; the way you have written `obj` is only created in the else block, when the request method is `POST`, `obj` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commit=False. You're telling django not to commit your changes. I don't believe obj exists in your post method if statement. It only exists in your else statement.

Comment: did you do .save() and did you correct your typeo that Daniel Roseman pointed out?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to bring the last two lines back one indentation level, so they will be executed when the form is posted but not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting `/contact/success` (which is why that page loads), but the new contact is never created because your view method's URL `/contact/edit/` is not being called.

You need to fix your form URL.

Comment: if ill change url django doesnt find url pattern..

but it needs to redirect success page..

Comment: u r right....
<form method="post" action="/contact/edit/{{p_id}}"  class="form-signin">

it works... :)
thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
Contact instance should be placed at top

indent last two lines of views.py

def edit_contact_page(request,p_id):

     obj=Contact.objects.get(pk=p_id)
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ContactForm(request.POST,instance=obj)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/success')
     else :
         form=ContactForm(instance=obj)
     variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form, 'p_id': p_id})
     return render_to_response('registration/edit_contact.html',variables)

form url
<form method="post" action="/contact/edit/{{p_id}}"  class="form-signin">
```